# How to use routerLink that go to child without changing parent dynamic param

Tags: angular, routerlink

I am trying to route to a child link without changing parent param.

```
{
    path: ':lang',
    children: [
        { path: 'books', component: BooksComponent },
    ]
}
```

This is what I tried I also tried other methods but haven't worked till now.

```
[routerLink]="[lang, '/books']"
```

Comment: try [routerLink]="[lang+'/books']"

Comment: Just tried it doesn't work. However if I use it like this [routerLink]="['/'+lang+'/books']" it goes to /undefined/books. Am I calling the lang parameter wrong?

Comment: But then it will go to /lang/books I want the lang to be dynamic. So depending on the current param it can be 'en' or 'nl' for example.

Comment: ah, okay, I thougt lang is a string: `lang`. Then disregard what I said :D

Comment: But anyway, then lang is undefined when you are trying to route. Make sure `lang` has a value :)

Comment: The lang is declared as a param within the router ':lang'. I can use a service to get the route param but in the official angular docs just by calling the param name inside the routerLink it should work. Can't seem to understand why not in my case.

Comment: You'd have to create a plunker to showcase the issue, otherwise it's almost impossible to help you.